# Cannot trigger opening of Internet browser report from within Arelle

Tags: xbrl, arelle

Using arelle 1.2020.05.10 (64-bit) git master branch, with Python 3.6.9.
Installed Edgar Renderer 36.0.2 git master branch.
Opening a iXBRL file either from local machine or through URL does not open an internet browser to show the iXBRL document. I am able of starting the "Arelle web services" and connecting to localhost:8080. But I would prefer to have the browser triggered from Arelle GUI.

No visible errors in terminal.
In Arelle message I see:

```
[Warn] "The rendering engine was unable to produce output due to an internal error. This is not concidered an error in the filing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser works from Arelle by loading master on both Arelle and Edgar Rendered, + installing all required python package dependencies.